# CiviVolunteer enabled but not showing in navigation

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

I'm attempting to get CiviVolunteer up & going on our wordpress installation of CiviCRM 4.5.8

It's enabled but not showing in the navigation.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When a new Extension or Component is added you may find there are Permissions that need to be enabled, and that might be why you don't see it in the menu.

Alternatively go to Administer > Customise > Navigation Menu, check if it is in that list, if it is, but not showing, right click on it and 'save' and then you should see a new option on the screen that says "Click here to reload the page and see your changes in the menu bar above. " and that might be enough of a nudge.

Comment: Bless you, bless you for answering! Should the permissions of the entire plugins directory be 777? It was mostly 755.

Comment: Hi Nancy, i actually meant permissions which in a Drupal sense would be the Drupal User permissions, and WP has equivalent at <yoursite>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll check that. I believe the root of the problem is that CiviCRM was originally installed elsewhere & kind of half-way moved to the current location. So the extension path & URL remains at the old location. I'm trying to move forward with using the volunteer functionality even though it's not linked in the top navigation.

Comment: good luck - if it as an unsuccessful or incomplete move then you might find it bites you at other points too.